# OSX 10.7 + virtualbox 4.2 + Windows 8 + iSight webcam = awfully slow

Tags: macos, windows-8, virtualbox, webcam

I'm running Windows 8 on VirtualBox on Mac OSX. I wanted to enable iSight webcam and went to USB Devices, and ticked iSight cam. At this point the Windows becomes so slow it is virtually impossible to use. Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have the USB device set to usb 1.1.

Follow this guide to download the USB 2.0 support pack

http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-download-install-oracle-vm-virtualbox-extension-pack-windows-host

If it still does not play ball, Parallels has perfect USB support.

Comment: In the mean time I'm using trial version of VMWare Fusion and it also seems to work well. Will try the support pack you recommended, but VMWAre also has the better way of handling resolution so I might just shell out 50 bucks for it.